# Accessing a function from a MovieClip in an Array - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a 2d shooter and trying to have different attacks have different effects on certain enemy types. I have my bullets and Enemies put into two arrays and then use a for loop which does a hitTestObject on the bullets and enemies. This all works, but then I have a public static function inside of the Bullet class which returns it's type as a String and a public static function inside of the Enemy class that takes a String then uses a switch to deiced what damage the enemy receives. When I run my program I keep getting Error #1069: Property getType not found on obj.QuickBullet and there is no default value.

The code for the Enemy.

```
package char {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Enemy1 extends MovieClip {

    private var _type:String;
    private static var _health:Number;
    private var _vx:Number;
    private var _vy:Number;
    private var _stage:Stage;

    private static var _instance:Enemy1;

    public function Enemy1() {
        init();
    }

    private function init():void {
        //Vars
        _vx = -10;
        _vy = Math.random()*10;
        _health = 1;
        _stage = Main.getStage();
        _instance = this;

        //Listeners
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);

        //Add Enemy
        Main.getInstance().addChild(this);
    }

    //When Added
    private function onAdded(event:Event):void{
        //Set position
        this.x = _stage.stageWidth;
        this.y = Math.random() * _stage.stageHeight;
        //trace("Enemy created");

        dispatchEvent(new Event("enemyCreated", true));
    }

    //Loop
    private function enemyLoop(event:Event):void {
        //Move
        x += _vx;
        y += _vy;

        //Boundaries
        if ( this.y <= 0 + this.height/2){
            this.y = this.height/2;
            _vy *= -1;
        }
        if ( this.y >= _stage.stageHeight - this.width/2){
            this.y = _stage.stageHeight - this.width/2;
            _vy *= -1;
        }

        //Health cheack
        if ( _health <= 0){
            if (this.parent) {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
            trace(this + " is dead.");
        }
        //Leaves screen
        if (this.x <= -this.width){
            Main.getInstance().removeChild(this);
        }
    }

    public static function isHit(type:String):void{
        switch(type){
            case "power" :
                _health -= 1;
                break;
            case "quick" :
                _health -= 1;
                break;
            case "strong" :
                _health -= 1;
                break;
            default:
                    _health -= 1;
            }
        }

        public static function getEnemy1():Enemy1{
            return _instance;
        }

        //When Removed
        private function onRemoved(event:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
            removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);
            //trace("enemy removed");
        }
    }

}
```

Code for the Bullet.

```
package obj {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;


public class PowerBullet extends MovieClip {
    //const
    private static const TYPE:String = "power";

    //Varibles
    private var _vx:Number;
    private var _vy:Number;
    private var _startX:Number;
    private var _startY:Number;
    private var _stage:Stage;

    public function PowerBullet(startX:Number, startY:Number) {
        _startX = startX;
        _startY = startY;

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        Main.getInstance().addChild(this);
    }

    //When created
    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void{
        //Initialize vars
        this.x = _startX;
        this.y = _startY;
        _vx = 20;
        _vy = 0;
        _stage = Main.getStage();

        dispatchEvent(new Event("bulletCreated", true));

        //Event Handlers
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletLoop);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);
    }

    //Bullet loop
    private function bulletLoop(event:Event):void {
        //Move bullet
        x += _vx;
        y += _vy;

        if (this.x - this.width > _stage.stageWidth)
        {
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }

    public static function getType():String{
        return TYPE;
    }

    //When Removed
    private function onRemoved(event:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletLoop);
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved);
    }
}

}
```

The for loop I'm using.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < _enemies.length; i++){
for(var j:int = 0; j < _bullets.length; j++){
    if(_bullets[j].hitTestObject(_enemies[i])){
        if (_bullets[j].parent) {
                            _bullets[j].parent.removeChild(_bullets[j]);
                    }

                    _enemies[i].isHit(_bullets[j].getType());

                    _enemies.splice(i, 1);
                    _bullets.splice(j, 1);

                    i--;
                    j--;

                    Main.setScore(10);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Your error is saying there is no property `getType()` on `QuickBullet` but you've only supplied code for `PowerBullet`.

You have the `static` namespace applied to `getType()`. This means you can only call this method via the class itself rather than an instance of that class:

```
PowerBullet.getType();
```

If you remove `static`, you'll be able to access that method on each instance like expected.

Additional note: It looks like you're using `static` for a few class members where it doesn't seem logical like `health` and `isHit()`. I suggest you read up on the static namespace to better understand its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `static` from this code

```
public static function getType():String{
    return TYPE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and I'll definitely read up on the static namespace.